# PHP mysqli extension in Ubuntu 16.04 not working after upgrade to version 7.0.6

Tags: apache2, 16.04, php, php7

After update this morning php does not work any more. Error:

> AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined
>   function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/html/public_html/.../config.php
>   on line 2\n', referer: http://localhost/public_html/

php -v

> PHP 7.0.6-9+donate.sury.org~xenial+2 (cli) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2016 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016
>   Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

The libraries were installed before, took me quite some time to adapt after dist-upgrading to 16.04

Comment: Please check `sudo apt-get install php-mysql; sudo service apache2 restart`.

Comment: # sudo dpkg -l php*|grep php |wc -l
145
Believe me, the absolute basics I tried already.

Answer (score 17):

Without more information I can only describe general causes:

1. `php7.0-mysql` package is not installed, to fix run `sudo apt-get install php-mysql`
2. `mysqli` module got somehow disabled, to fix run `phpenmod mysqli`
3. You are using different web SAPI PHP version than you have PHP CLI, f.e. you might have installed `libapache2-mod-php5.6` with `php7.0-cli`
4. Your Apache 2.x configuration contains different PHP FPM version (f.e. `php5.6-fpm` package) and Apache2 module (f.e. `libapache2-mod-php7.0`).  Disable the FPM by running: `a2disconf php5.5-fpm`.
5. The web SAPI, you are using for web has different configuration file and thus mysqli module is not loaded, to fix add `extension=mysqli.so` to this custom configuration file
6. something else is broken and you should lookup for log messages indicating what's broken

To get more diagnostics:

1. run `php -r 'phpinfo();' and check the output for MySQL references:

   ```
   $ php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep -i mysqli
   /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
   mysqli
   MysqlI Support => enabled
   mysqli.allow_local_infile => On => On
   mysqli.allow_persistent => On => On
   mysqli.default_host => no value => no value
   mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306
   mysqli.default_pw => no value => no value
   mysqli.default_socket => no value => no value
   mysqli.default_user => no value => no value
   mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
   mysqli.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
   mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off
   mysqli.rollback_on_cached_plink => Off => Off
   API Extensions => mysql,mysqli,pdo_mysql
   ```
2. Do the same with the web, create a simple page with just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and check the output for MySQLI module. If installed, you'll see an entire section like the following:
   [image: phpinfo mysqli section]

After further looking into the issue, we found out, that there was a mix of PHP 5.5 and PHP 7.0 in the system that probably confused Apache2.  As a general recommendation I would definitely recommend start with one PHP version to debug and purge the other(s).

To completely purge a specific PHP version, you can purge `phpX.Y-common` package that will pull all the other reverse dependencies:

Example:

```
apt-get purge php5.5-common # to remove PHP 5.5
apt-get purge php5.6-common # to remove PHP 5.6
apt-get purge php7.0-common # to remove PHP 7.0
# and to remove old php5 packages:
apt-get purge php5-common # to remove old PHP 5.x packages
```

Comment: php -r 'phpinfo();' |grep mysqli gives
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
mysqli
mysqli.allow_local_infile => On => On
mysqli.allow_persistent => On => On
mysqli.default_host => no value => no value
mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306
mysqli.default_pw => no value => no value
mysqli.default_socket => no value => no value
mysqli.default_user => no value => no value
mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off
mysqli.rollback_on_cached_plink => Off => Off
API Extensions => mysqli,pdo_mysql

Comment: Seems MysqlI Support => enabled is missing. Which config file should I add extension=mysqli.so ?

Comment: Run `sudo phpenmod mysqli` or reinstall php7.0-mysql with: `sudo apt-get purge php7.0-mysql && sudo apt-get install php-mysql`

Comment: no help. Did reinstall as you posted but exactly same error. The strange thing it happend after an upgrade (not distupgrade!).

Comment: What does `ldd /usr/lib/php/*/mysqli.so` output?

Comment: linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd3a1fe000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f343c901000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000561b95430000)

Comment: sudo phpenmod mysqli >>WARNING: Module mysqli ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/5.5/mods-available

Comment: So you need that for PHP 5.5? Then you obviously need to install php5.5-mysql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40009/discussion-between-user30424-and-oerdnj).